# How to capture a sentence but ignore whitespace more than 1 with regex?

Tags: regex

My goal is to capture this string.

```
      04/07          TRSF E-BANKING DB                0207/QEZDF/WSA2321                                           500.00 DB
                     TANGGAL :02/07                   Q0344XXXXX12
                                                      SALZXA YAEAS SAX
```

What I've tried:

1. The regex used: `(\d{2}/\d{2})([ ]{1,}[\w -]*)`

However, the `[\w -]*` capture `TRSF E-BANKING DB`                 instead of just the `TRSF E-BANKING DB`.

I am not sure how to tell the regex within the match case that the whitespace length should not be more than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the pattern as:

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}) +([\w-]+(?: [\w-]+)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\d{2}\/\d{2})` Capture group 1, match 2 digits, `/` and 2 digits
- `+` Match 1 or more spaces
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `[\w-]+` Match 1+ word chars or `-`
  - `(?: [\w-]+)*` Optionally repeat matching 1 space and 1 or more word chars or `-`
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SluyDu/1)